# i'm not abble to fix this syntax prob in php string

Tags: php

```php
if ( $home_blocks['type'] == "slider_banner" ) {
                    echo '<div class="om_home_sec_slider_main" style="margin:'.$home_blocks['settings']['margin'].';">';
                    foreach ($home_blocks['content'] as $slides_content) {
                        echo '<div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-7 d-flex flex-column">
                                <h3 class="mb-0 om_font_size_15 font-weight-bold slide_heading_mt">'.$slides_content['Heading'['text'].'</h3>
                                <span class="om_mid_txt_my om_font_size_08">'.$slides_content['paragraph'['text'].'</span>
                                <div class="d-flex home_slide_btn_div">';
                                    $new_var = $slides_content['buttons'];
                                    foreach( $new_var as $buttons) {
                                        if ( $buttons['type'] == "delivery") {
                                            echo '<button class="font-weight-bold om_font_size_02 om_btn_02 om_clor_white">'.$buttons['text'].'</button>';
                                        }
                                        else ( $buttons['type'] == "take_away") {
                                            echo '<button class="font-weight-bold om_btn_05 om_font_size_02 om_clr_green">'.$buttons['text'].'</button>';
                                        }                                       
                                    }                                   
                                echo '</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <img class="mw-100" src="'.$slides_content['image'].'" alt="pic"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
                    }
```

Comment: `else` blocks do not take arguments. You want `else if`. `$slides_content['Heading'['text']` and `$slides_content['paragraph'['text']` are completely incorrect.

Comment: You missed a closing bracket "}" at the end too.